# How to use GroupBy correctly from multiple joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm

I have the following table imagetable...

[image]

And this is my query...

```
SELECT w.name as wholesaler_name,
       w.outlet_id,
       w.distributor_name,
       w.distributor_id,
       wt.name as tipe_plus,
       v.target,
       v.week as periode,
       SUM(v.total_transaction),
       v.rebate,
       v.total_voucher
FROM voucher v
JOIN wholesalers w ON w.id=v.wholesaler_id
JOIN wholesaler_types wt ON w.wholesaler_type_id=wt.id
GROUP BY w.name,
         w.outlet_id,
         w.distributor_name,
         w.distributor_id,
         wt.name,
         v.target,
         v.week,
         v.rebate,
         v.total_voucher;
```

In the `periode` column, there is `2` of the same period (`11.2017`) for one `wholesaler_name`.  I want it so that if that happens the `total_transaction` column will `SUM()`.

I use `GROUP BY` but the result is still same.

Hope you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chek `total_vouchers` column.

In your query everething will be ok if `total_vouchers` are same for `11.2017`, because your query finaly step will want grouping by `total_vouchers` , in your result link i can not see `total_vouchers`, if they are not same for `11.2017` then exclude that column from `group by` and select or put that column in Sum(), Count().... (aggregate function) in `select` Section

Comment: i see, i realized that total_voucher in 11.2017 is different, and now i change to sum(total_voucher) and delete total_voucher in group by, and its work.
thankyou. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sub-query to simplify your sql statement.

```
select * from
(
    SELECT yourPK, v.week as periode, sum(v.total_transaction)
    FROM voucher v
    JOIN wholesalers w ON w.id=v.wholesaler_id
    JOIN wholesaler_types wt ON w.wholesaler_type_id=wt.id
   GROUP BY yourpk, periode
) SumResult
join TheOthersTable on SumResult.yourPK = TheOthersTable.yourPK
```

Answer (score 0):

Check other column in the result.
For Example if one col